# i can't reset password in laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

when i code password/reset i find this error :  **User must implement CanResetPassword interface.**

can i code this manually or change some thing in my code ?
I can't find where is the probleme exactly , can you help me 
my model User is :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail,CanResetPassword
{
    use Notifiable;


    public function fillier(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Fillier');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'is_admin', 'is_represantant',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CanResetPassword` in L7 is included by default. You don't need to implement it explicitly. As per documentation:

> The `App\User` model included with the framework already implements this interface

Comment: But sir , in documentation i found this  <<  To get started, verify that your App\User model implements the Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword >> it mean that use CanResetPassword; ??

Comment: Edited my answer.